# how to pass two arrays to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops

Im not pro in programming

i have a foreach loop that gets the values from a form calculating the total and subtotal

```
 public function salecal()
{
    if ($this->input->post())
    {

        $i = 0;
        $data = array();
        $subtotal = 0;

        foreach($this->input->post('pname') as $d){


            $data[] = array(
                'pid' => $this->input->post('pid[]')[$i],
                'pname' => $this->input->post('pname[]')[$i],
                'quantity' => $this->input->post('qty[]')[$i],
            );

            foreach ($data as $entry) {

                    $qty = $entry['quantity'];
                    $pid = $entry['pid'];
                    $proname = $entry ['pname'];

            }

            $value = $this->insert_model->get_price($pid); ///pasing the product id to get the the price from database

            foreach ($value->result() as $row)
            {
                $price = $row->price;
            }

            $total = $price * $qty; ////Total calculation


            $subtotal = $subtotal + $total;/////Sub Total Calculation

            $i++;


        }

        $result = compact("proname", "price", "qty", "total","i", "subtotal");

        $this->load->view("bill", $result);

    }

}
```

when i run this code im getting only the finally entered products details but the subtotal is correct

but the data inserting form is dynamic

what i want as result is

user will insert several or one item with quantity

data should be calculated and pass the calculated values to view

but currently im getting it only for the last inserted data please help me how to catch all the datas that user insert to form and how to pass them to view

Comment: because your overwriting the variable consequently so it's passing last overwrite value only . you should make array for each one

Comment: @JtoThl Please help me how can i do that?

and the input fields may be change depend on the items that user insert

Comment: can you check my below answer and removed that useless array build and foreach too . @Rizkan Mohamed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your overwriting the variables consequently so it's passing last overwrite value only . you should make array for each one

This how you need to send all data to view using array

```
    <?php

    public function salecal()
    {
        if ($this->input->post())
        {

            $i = 0;
            $data = array();
            $subtotal = 0;

            $final_array_collection =array();

            foreach($this->input->post('pname') as $d){

                $total =0; //reset the total to zero for each product

                $pid = $this->input->post('pid[]')[$i];
                $pname = $this->input->post('pname[]')[$i];
                $quantity = $this->input->post('qty[]')[$i];

                $value = $this->insert_model->get_price($pid); ///pasing the product id to get the the price from database

                foreach ($value->result() as $row)
                {
                    $price = $row->price;
                }

                $total = $price * $quantity; ////Total calculation


                $subtotal = $subtotal + $total;/////Sub Total Calculation


                $final_array_collection[] =array("proname"=>$pname, "price"=>$price, "qty"=>$quantity, "total"=>$total,"i"=>$i, "subtotal"=> $subtotal);

                $i++;


            }

            $result = compact("final_array_collection");

            $this->load->view("bill", $result);

        }

    }



    ?>
```

Comment: @JyoThl Thanks a lot your Answer solved my problem Thanks a lot

Comment: glad to help you @RizkanMohamed